# Use of @Bean in Spring 5

Tags: spring, service, javabeans

Hi Team could anyone please explain me if
the spring @Bean and @Service with @Transactional  serve the same purpose in Spring 5. To me if i declare @Service with @Transactional i dont need @Bean for that class?